# Using 2 AC-DC adapters in parallel with block diodes to safely increase current capacity

Tags: diodes, ac-dc

The way I understand it, if doubling up 2 AC-DC adapters one might output a slightly higher voltage than the other, and only a very slight voltage imbalance could lead to a larger current imbalance, and one unit would be doing all the work so to speak.

Can this be mitigated by putting a diode in series on each positive output?

Specifically block diodes from solar panels? I have several 2 A, 12 V AC-DC adapters and lots of large solar panel diodes. I would like to power a DC motor that draws 2.75 A under normal load.

Comment: Long story short: don’t. Get yourself a suitable power supply and avoid all hassle.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed try this, but you have to keep in mind several things:

- Diodes have a forward voltage drop, I'm not entirely sure about solar panel blocking diodes, but seeing as they tolerate higher power, they might have a larger forward voltage drop, which would reduce your power supply voltage.
- If you have power supplies that are not exactly intelligent and shut down when reaching 2A, you won't be able to power the load. Your supplies have to support a constant current mode at 2A for this to work.
- The power supply might have more features that may prevent this from working, check their datasheet to see if it says anything about parallel connections.

Overall, I would say the simplest choice is getting a power supply that can tolerate higher current, they're not very expensive.

Comment: Thanks, i'll give it a go and find out.  I'm remote, no shops unfortunately, have to work with what I have.  I'm willing to try it, I just didn't want to make needless e-waste if it was fundamentally destined to fail.

Comment: Make sure you do it safely. If the power supplies end up having no protection or something else wrong, you can cause a fire hazard, so be careful!

Comment: Solar panel block diodes are a good choice here. They have a very low forward voltage drop, but they are sensitive to ESD.

Answer (score 0):

If you understand the problem is that no two power supplies are identical, then consider that no two diodes are identical either.

Small series so-called "current-balancing" resistors do work though since they provide negative feedback and some slack to drop the voltage difference across. The split won't be exactly 50-50 though. Higher resistances means more equal split but more losses. It's a tradeoff. We are talking low single-digit Ohms, or even less.

But if you disconnect the load then the supplies will still backfeed into one another if you only have resistors. So you could use diodes and resistors.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that the easiest solution is to get a power supply that is rated for your application.

However, there are times when it seems appropriate to combine power from two sources. Diodes can help prevent back-powering a weaker source. However, if two power sources act as rather stiff voltage sources, and their voltages differ, one may still have problems. The weaker supply may be unable to contribute any current at all. Or the supplies may take turns going into thermal shutdown. Or...

There are a number of solutions to getting two power supplies to share a load. But the simplest is with load sharing resistors.

The basic idea is this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOPSyc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In this case, one of the power supplies is 120 mV lower than the other. However, the stronger power supply provides 1.954 A, and the weaker 754 mA. Thus both supplies are working within their rated tolerance.

There is some voltage droop because of the resistors. 1.954 A through a 100 m\$\Omega\$ resistor gives a drop of 195 mV. 750 mA through the 100 m\$\Omega\$ resistor gives a drop of 75 mV. If I have done my math correctly, 12V - 195mV = 11.805 V which should equal 11.88 V - 75 mV = 11.805 V.

The theory is that the source with the higher voltage passes more current so there is a larger voltage drop through the resistor. The source with the lower voltage passes less current, so there is a lower voltage drop. However, on the common side of the resistors, the voltages will be exactly the same.

If the voltage difference between the sources can be expected to be greater than the 120 mV shown in the schematic, or the current drawn by the load may be more than 2.75A, then the resistors may be increased in value. However, the larger the value of the resistors, the larger the voltage and power lost.

Again, this is only one of the ways of balancing two power supplies to share a load. However, it is by far the simplest. Also, again, in *your* particular case, it may be easiest to simply purchase a more powerful supply. Finally, once again, this does not obviate the need for diodes to protect the voltage supplies from back-feed. This technique only answers the question of how one might ensure that the lower voltage supply contributes a share of the current to the load. There are other methods, but this is the simplest.